# Python: Output the most frequent number, and its quantity

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, the question is, I have a list of 30 random, repetitive numbers and I have to find the most frequent number and how many times it is repeated.

For example: The list is
`[10, 10, 11, 11, 1, 10, 5, 7, 19, 7, 3, 11, 7, 15, 16, 20, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3, 11, 20, 14, 5, 15, 2, 14, 20, 6]`
and from this list, the result that i'm expected to show is 11, 4times 7, 4times.

I've been trying but i seem to be lost and i can't clearly figure out a way beyond making alist and writing for i in list:

Comment: Do you want to show just a single number with the highest count or all numbers with their count?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this using base Python; **without** `itertools` or `collections` would be:

```
d = {}
mylist = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]

for i in set(mylist):
    d[i] = mylist.count(i)
```

Then, sort the `dict` to determine the most frequent, etc.

This answer is posted for educational purposes, showing a lower-level way to accomplish this task, without the use of a library.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this,

```
import collections
numbers = [1,2,2,3,3]
data = collections.Counter(numbers)
data_list = dict(data)
max_value = max(list(data.values()))
mode_val = [num for num, freq in data_list.items() if freq == max_value]
if len(mode_val) == len(numbers):
    print("No mode in the list")
else:
    print('mode: ',mode_val)
x= {y:numbers.count(y) for y in mode_val}
print('times: ',x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways, this is just one solution

```
from statistics import multimode

in_list = [10, 10, 11, 11, 1, 10, 5, 7, 19, 7, 3, 11, 7, 15, 16, 20, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3, 11, 20, 14, 5, 15, 2, 14, 20, 6]
highest_frequency_nos = multimode(in_list)
print(' '.join('{}, {}times'.format(item, in_list.count(item)) for item in highest_frequency_nos))
```

`in_list.count(element)` will return number of times the specified element appears in the list.

Reference:
[python statistics.multimode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode)

Answer (score 0):

I am still a newbie, I tried this and it worked and I hope you will find it easy to read. However, I would upvote a more concise solution as experienced users have already given :)

```
from collections import Counter


data = [10, 10, 11, 11, 1, 10, 5, 7, 19, 7, 3, 11, 7, 15, 16, 20, 9, 7, 4, 2, 3, 11, 20, 14, 5, 15, 2, 14, 20, 6]


def most_frequent_number_finder(your_list):
    occurence_count = Counter(your_list)
    return occurence_count.most_common(1)[0][0]


most_frequent_number = (most_frequent_number_finder(data))


most_frequent_number_count  = data.count(most_frequent_number)


print(f"Your most frequent number is {most_frequent_number} with a count of {most_frequent_number_count}")
```

##prints:
Your most frequent number is 11 with a count of 4

---

Also what would you do if there is a duplicate number with the same occurrence, something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote many moons ago when experimenting with a Loto number generator.

```
# test random number generation
print('   This program experiments with random number generation\n')
#
loop = int(input('Enter a number for generating set`s of 50 throws > '))
print()
#
import random
#
x = 0
#
y = 0
#
throws = [[] for i in range (50)]
#
while loop > 0:
    print('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv')
    print('                           loop value', loop)                  
    loop = loop -1
    for i in range(0, 50):
        #
        x = random.random()
        #
        #
        x = x * 49 // 1
        #
        y = int(x)
        #
        #
        throws [i] = y
        #
    print('                     list of 50 throw`s')
        #  
    print(throws)
    print()
    for i in range (0, 50):
        #
        if throws.count(i) >= 1:
            #
            print (throws.count(i), 'times ', i, 'thrown')
        else:
            print ('                   ', i, 'Not thrown')
```